# Why all the testcases are not passing? palindrome program

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pointers, data-structures

Given a string `s`, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.

Why is the below solution not accepting some of the test cases?

```
s = "".join(s)
s = s.lower()
if s==s[::-1]:
    return "true"
else:
    return "false"
```

Input: `s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"`

Output: `true`

This test case is accepted:

Input: `s = "race a car"`

Output: `false`

this test case is returning true instead of false

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is [returning false](https://ideone.com/Z2jh4h) for both cases.

According to this part in the question

> considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.

you could remove all non alphanumeric chars from the string first using re.sub and a pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` matching all chars except the listed alphanumeric ranges.

```
import re
strings = [
    "race a car",
    "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
]

for s in strings:
    s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "", "".join(s).lower())
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print("true: for {0}".format(s))
    else:
        print("false: for {0}".format(s))
```

Output

```
false: for raceacar
true: for amanaplanacanalpanama
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZBrdwI)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on using regex, you can use isalnum() string method:

```
s = ''.join(element for element in s if element.isalnum()).lower()
if s==s[::-1]:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

All are returning false because you don't remove spaces and special characters...

`A man, a plan, a canal: Panama` becomes: `amanap :lanac a ,nalp a ,nam a`